# Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, void, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

iam using  react-Redux-Toolkit + createAsyncThunk . I'm asking this question because an error occurred during development.

categorySlice.js:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import useGetData from "hooks/useGetDate";

const initialState = {
  category: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

export const getAllCategory = createAsyncThunk(
  "category/getAll",
  async (url, thunkAPI) => {
    const { rejectWithValue } = thunkAPI;
    try {
      const res = await useGetData(url);
      return res.data;
    } catch (err) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
  }
);

export const categorySlice = createSlice({
  name: "category",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getAllCategory.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(getAllCategory.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = null;
        state.category = action.payload; // Assuming action.payload is an array of categories
      })
      .addCase(getAllCategory.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action?.error?.message;
      });
  },
});

export default categorySlice.reducer;
```

AllCategoryPage.js(my component):

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import CategoryContainer from "../../Components/Category/CategoryContainer";
import Pagination from "../../Components/Uitily/Pagination";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getAllCategory } from "redux/categorySlice";

const AllCategoryPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.categoryData.category);
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.categoryData.loading);
  const error = useSelector((state) => state.categoryData.error);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllCategory("/api/v1/categories"));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div style={{ minHeight: "670px" }}>
      <CategoryContainer />
      <Pagination />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllCategoryPage;
```

the errors:

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/dell/Downloads/08-ecommerce-design-only-master/design/src/Page/Category/AllCategoryPage.js",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2554",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 14,
    "startColumn": 29,
    "endLineNumber": 14,
    "endColumn": 49
}]
```

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/dell/Downloads/08-ecommerce-design-only-master/design/src/Page/Category/AllCategoryPage.js",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2345",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, void, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 14,
    "startColumn": 14,
    "endLineNumber": 14,
    "endColumn": 50
}]
```

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/dell/Downloads/08-ecommerce-design-only-master/design/src/Page/Category/AllCategoryPage.js",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2339",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Property 'categoryData' does not exist on type 'unknown'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 10,
    "startColumn": 50,
    "endLineNumber": 10,
    "endColumn": 62
}]
```

First time using this and work at project, so a nice explanation please.

i cant use and dispatch the data at my component

Comment: Please follow the TypeScript quick start, especially https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#use-typed-hooks-in-components

Comment: @phry  
but i am using JS not TS

Comment: Then why do you ask about TypeScript error messages?

Comment: @phry
i use js but there is this TypeScript error messages i dont how or why

Comment: Your editor probably uses TypeScript to give you autocomplete and tries to check your JavaScript code. Without you writing TypeScript, that might result in weird errors like this. 
If you don't want that, that's probably an editor setting you'd need to disable - although I'd really recommend using TypeScript from the start.

Comment: @phry
i think if editor uses TypeScript maybe will be errors at file but the code should be success and process of dispatch data supposed to Done successfully.
Anyway, I use visual studio code and he give TS automatic activation, but for many things, I don't know what exactly I should disable.